# Error Missing $ inserted, Help!

Tags: math-mode

Buen  día tengo un trabajo y quiero poner algunas cosas, soy nuevo en esto asi que me surgieron muchas dudas, este es mi codigo:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\title{4.2 Funciones Integrables}
\author{J.~Zacarias\inst{} \and P.~Rodr\'iguez\inst{} \and H.~Dom\'inguez \inst{}}
\institute[] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
  \inst{}%
  Universidad Aut\'onoma de Yucat\'an\\
  Facultad de Matem\'aticas}
\date{Viernes 4 de diciembre de 2015}
\subject{}
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Funciones Integrables}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
% Let's get started
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Fundamentos y conceptos b\'asicos de integraci\'on`}
\begin{block}{Definici\'on 4.2.1.}
Sea $f : A \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\ $acotada .Si $B$ \subset\ A \ $definimos$: \\
 \item 
    \centering $M_B(f)=sup \{f(x) : x\in B\}\\
 \item
    \centering $m_B(f) = inf\{f(x) : x\in B\}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. My Spanish is pretty bad, but I think your first equation should be `Sea $f: A \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ acotada. Si $B \subset A$ definimos:`. Since TeX ignores single line breaks, you may want to split regular text and math expressions onto their own lines, making it easier for you to keep the `$` or `\(` and `\)` symbols balanced.

Comment: Also after both `\item`s you have `$ ...` you need `$ ... $`, e.g. `$M_B(f)=sup \{f(x) : x\in B\}` should be `$M_B(f)=sup \{f(x) : x\in B\}$`. In other news, `sup` ---> `\sup`, `inf` ---> `\inf`

Answer (score 5):

Your input has some glitches; you are mainly forgetting to balance opening and closing `$` for formulas. Here's a part of your code.

```
\begin{block}{Definici\'on 4.2.1.}
Sea $f : A \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\ $acotada .Si $B$ \subset\ A \ $definimos$: \\
 \item 
    \centering $M_B(f)=sup \{f(x) : x\in B\}\\
 \item
    \centering $m_B(f) = inf\{f(x) : x\in B\}
\end{block}
```

1. In general, the closing `$` is followed either by a space or punctuation; don't put the space before it.
2. The sentence ending period must be next to the final word
3. A formula contains everything that's math: `$B\subset A$`
4. Names of common functions such as logarithm, supremum, infimum and so on, should be written in upright font.
5. Don't substitute display math mode with `\centering`
6. Recall that `\centering` continues until the end of the current group

Fixed version

```
\begin{block}{Definici\'on 4.2.1.}
Sea $f\colon A \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ acotada.
Si $B \subset A$ definimos:
\begin{gather*}
M_B(f)=sup \{f(x) : x\in B\}\\
m_B(f) = inf\{f(x) : x\in B\}
\end{gather*}
\end{block}
```